# Error in MySql query

Tags: mysql, syntax-error

I have three tables.  I am attempting to pull data from two tables and insert into the third if a set of circumstances exists.  When I run my query I am getting

> "#1054 - Unknown column 'rvp_to_registrants_to_events.rvp_to_registrants_id' in 'where clause' "

Here is my query:

```
INSERT INTO  rvp_to_registrants_to_events (rtr.rvp_to_registrants_id, rte.events_id)



SELECT
    rtr.rvp_to_registrants_id, rte.events_id

FROM
    registrants_to_events rte,rvp_to_registrants rtr


WHERE (
    SELECT
        rte.registrants_id, rte.events_id, 
        rtr.rvp_to_registrants_id, rtr.registrants_id


    FROM
        registrants_to_events rte,rvp_to_registrants rtr


    WHERE
        rte.registrants_id = rtr.registrants_id

        AND (rtr.rvp_to_registrants_id != rvp_to_registrants_to_events.rvp_to_registrants_id

        AND rte.events_id != rvp_to_registrants_to_events.events_id)

    )
```

I can't figure out why I am getting this error.  I am sure it is something bonehead that I am overlooking, but any help appreciated.

Thanks!

Per Michael's input I have updated my code as follows.  Returning zero results now, so am working on that:

```
   INSERT INTO  rvp_to_registrants_to_events (rvp_to_registrants_id, events_id)

SELECT
    rtr.rvp_to_registrants_id, rte.events_id

FROM
  registrants_to_events rte 
  JOIN rvp_to_registrants rtr ON rte.registrants_id = rtr.registrants_id
  JOIN rvp_to_registrants_to_events rtrte ON rtr.rvp_to_registrants_id = rtrte.rvp_to_registrants_id

    WHERE  

        rte.registrants_id = rtr.registrants_id
    AND 
        (rtr.rvp_to_registrants_id !=  rtrte.rvp_to_registrants_id
    AND 
        rte.events_id != rtrte.events_id)
```

Comment: Well, does the table  `rvp_to_registrants_to_events` have a column named `rvp_to_registrants_id`?

Comment: yes, it does.I should have mentioned I double checked column names, etc for typos

Comment: It'll be easier for everyone if you can give your schemas.

Answer (score 1):

The error looks to be because you have referred to `rvp_to_registrants_to_events` in your `WHERE` clause, but not included it in your `FROM`:

```
FROM
    registrants_to_events rte,rvp_to_registrants rtr, rvp_to_registrants_to_events
WHERE
    rte.registrants_id = rtr.registrants_id
    AND (rtr.rvp_to_registrants_id != rvp_to_registrants_to_events.rvp_to_registrants_id
    AND rte.events_id != rvp_to_registrants_to_events.events_id)
```

I would recommend redefining this with a proper `JOIN` syntax:

```
FROM
  registrants_to_events rte 
  JOIN rvp_to_registrants rtr ON rte.registrants_id = rtr.registrants_id
  JOIN rvp_to_registrants_to_events ON rtr.registrants_id = rvp_to_registrants_to_events.registrants_id
  -- --------------------supply the correct ON clause relationship ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
WHERE
  -- actual selection criteria
```

You will need to supply the actual column relationship to the `ON` clause in place of `ON rtr.registrants_id = rvp_to_registrants_to_events.registrants_id`. The `JOIN` assumes there is a common column between `rvp_to_registrants_to_events` and either `rte` or `rtr` but that isn't clear to me.

Comment: actually, I aliased registrants_to_event as rte.  I didn't alias rvp_to_registrants_to_events at all.

Comment: @Keith Oops, see change above. the problem is that you don't include it in your `FROM` clause at all.

Comment: OK, I tried that and am now getting the error: #1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Comment: @Keith Hard to tell without being able to test myself, but I suspect it's because of the `()` in the `WHERE` clause. You haven't clearly defined the relationship of `rvp_to_registrants_to_events` to either of the other tables.

Comment: Thanks for sticking with this Michael.  I removed the parenteses because I realized the logic was essentially the same without them, and I still get the same error.  How could I more clearly define the relationship between the tables being that I am attempting to insert data into it, rather than pull data from it?

Comment: @Keith Try switching to a `JOIN` syntax as above.

Answer (score 0):

in your **from** cause you have :
 registrants_to_events rte,rvp_to_registrants rtr

in your **where** cause you use the table : 
rvp_to_registrants_to_events

This table should be in your **from** cause

Comment: I'm not sure I am following.  rvp_to_registrants_to_events is the table the data is being inserted into, registrants_to_events and rvp_to_registrants are the tables data is being pulled from.  I know the table names are cumbersome, but unfortunately I inherited them from the previous developer and can't change them.

Comment: Oh, I think you are saying the same thing as Michael.  Thx.  See above.

Comment: Thanks Nettogrof.  I'll check that out.

Answer (score 0):

To start, learn to use "JOIN" statements and table aliases in your code. It not only makes it easier to use but also understand. Essentially, your sql is doing that anyway but in its own interpretation.